# packet_write_wait: Broken Pipe error on MacOS Sierra SSH

Tags: macos, ssh

I keep getting a packet_write_wait: Broken Pipe error on my EC2 SSH connections after a period of inactivity.

I've tried modifying the `ServerAliveInterval` & `ClientAliveInterval` settings with different values ranging from `5` to `120`. I've also tried changing the `TCPKeepAlive` setting to `no` or `yes`.  I've tried applying these settings to the config at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `~/.ssh/config` (I've tried these in a `Host *` block and a `Host SERVER.COM` block.)

Yet, I keep getting disconnected with a packet_write_wait: Broken Pipe error.  How do I correct this issue?

Comment: Not on Sierra but the settings mentioned helped me on El Capitan. I just experienced this again when we had some ghost VMs running: two VMs with the same IP. So I would be able to connect to the VM and then it kicked me out. Sometimes I could not connect as it complained that the host keys changed. And when I successfully sshed into it it would kick me out very fast. Is this happening to you on all machines you connect to? Did it start immediately after the Sierra upgrade? Can you see if it happens if you ping the machine from another terminal window? Have you checked the logs on the server?

Comment: I had looked up the issue on my previous mac (8-core Xeon) and solved the problem on El Capitan.  Then, I just recently upgraded to a new 4ghz 5k iMac with Sierra.  Now, the problem is back and I'm not exactly sure how I solved this the last time around.  I do remember having to try a few different settings and needing to log out / log back in or restart the SSH to get the settings to take.  The client machine hasn't changed so these issues *should* be all Mac-related.  Which log file might I want to check?

Comment: My changes were made on the client machine (with this I mean my Macbook Pro - as ssh client who connects to an server through ssh). I did not change anything on the server side (sshd config - for which a service restart is needed if changed). I checked some of my servers and the `TCPKeepAlive` setting is default (not changed) and `Yes`. On my client side i have added the `TCPKeepAlive` `Yes` and `ServerAliveInterval` `120` - which helped me to get rid of the kicking out.

Comment: Ah, I misspoke -- my server machine hasn't changed.  Hmm, I currently have the `TCPKeepAliv`e set to `Yes` and `ServerAliveInterval` set to `120` on both `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` & `~/.ssh/config`   Maybe there's a command to have SSH apply these settings?

Comment: if you `ssh -vvv <username>@<servername>` you should see in the ouput which lines were used by your client connection. On the server side a `service ssh restart` or `service sshd restart` (depending on OS) will read and apply the sshd settings.

Comment: Hmm, nothing noteworthy after using `ssh -vvv` I see `debug3: receive packet: type 82` `debug3: send packet: type 80` `debug3: send packet: type 1` `packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe`

Comment: Hard to tell without the whole output. You should make a compare with a -vvv output from a working connection. I was talking about lines like `debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *` so you can see which options are applied from the config files.

Comment: experiencing the same issue on Sierra. Tried everything, still fails. Disabling `TCPKeepAlive` kept connections open a bit longer, but still disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add "IPQoS throughput" to ssh_config in you mac

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain what the above suggestion does?