# packet_write_wait: Connection to @host port 22: Broken pipe

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, scp, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to copy some files from production server(ubuntu 16.04) to backup server(ubuntu 16.04) using scp command but getting

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to @host port 22: Broken pipe
Lost connection
```

I have tried adding

```
-o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o ServerAliveCountMax=5
```

from
[packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx port 3591: Broken pipe](https://superuser.com/questions/1331240/packet-write-wait-connection-to-xxx-port-3591-broken-pipe)
[packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx port 3591: Broken pipe](https://superuser.com/questions/1331240/packet-write-wait-connection-to-xxx-port-3591-broken-pipe)
[packet_write_wait: Broken Pipe error on MacOS Sierra SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/1137584/packet-write-wait-broken-pipe-error-on-macos-sierra-ssh)
but then its started throwing

```
Timeout, server @host not responding.
lost connection
```

I'm able to get the ssh connection to the backup server but not able to copy any files.
Point out something which I can do and copy files to backup server.Thanks in advance.

I found that I can copy files/folders upto 4k size to backup server but not bigger files. it's working when I'm trying to copy large files to another server but not on backup server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found fix by setting the LAN card's mtu setting to 1492 by

`# ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492`

Refer this link for more information : http://www.microhowto.info/howto/change_the_mtu_of_a_network_interface.html